# How to install new ngx-admin Material Themes?

Tags: material-design, themes, nebular, ngx-admin

I have .NET Core Akveo NGX Admin bundle and I'd like to know how to install new Material Themes in my current application. Anyone can help?

Comment: Do You have a solution?

Comment: To use material theme checkout feat/material-theme branch
https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/tree/feat/material-demo

Comment: @SurendraMourya I see that in the README they say read an article about backward-compatibility.. but where is that article ???